# Extracting Image Source via BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am struggling to extract a source image URL from a Snapchat wepbage (example [here](https://www.snap.com/en-US/political-ads/asset/ac58c252cd9981d0616351329540e7a5ef350d1f8d8feda7bc834ef9c3e73114?mediaType=png)).

I've tried a few solutions using BeautifulSoup. Here is what I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import regex as re


def extract_img_src(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    img_tags = soup.find_all('img')
    img_src_list = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]

    return img_src_list

url = 'https://www.snap.com/en-US/political-ads/asset/ac58c252cd9981d0616351329540e7a5ef350d1f8d8feda7bc834ef9c3e73114?mediaType=png'

img_src_list = extract_img_src(url)

for src in img_src_list:
    print(src)
```

But I am not getting what I want. For reference, here is the link of interest when inspecting the included webpage (the googleapi link):

[image]

Any help to extract that URL is appreciated!

Comment: If you open the page code source, you can see there are no img src links. They are loaded by javascript, you will need to use selenium